# Find the Fisher information matrix.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I'm trying to solve a problem:
[image]

But the parameter does not include variance itself, but standard deviation... Not sure how to approach the problem in this case...

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the chain rule; for example, if $l(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is your log-likelihood, then the first derivative with respect to $\sigma$ is:
$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial \sigma} = \frac{\partial l}{\partial \sigma^2}\frac{\partial \sigma^2}{\partial \sigma} = 2\sigma \frac{\partial l}{\partial \sigma^2}$$